# sup tag inside title tag html

Tags: javascript, html

I need registered trade mark as superscript in the tool tip. 
I tried using `sup` inside title tag

```
<p title="Normal <sup>R</sup>hello">Hello World</p>
```

but I see `sup` in the tooltip.

How to make sure that sup tag is ignore and R appears as a superscript inside the tooltip.

Comment: You can use unicode: ™ (copy/paste)

Answer (score 5):

Use `&reg;` instead.  You can probably also just write `®`.

Comment: i need R trademark as superscript and some countries have MD has their trademark symbol.

Comment: @abcabc that's really OS dependent (it's OSen that control the tooltips from the `title` attribute).  If you want to use html in titles, you could use a JavaScript plugin like qtip or tippy or something to make it real HTML.  Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Q3Bhs/1/

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
<p title = "Normal &#174; hello">Hello</p>
```

OR

```
<p title = "Normal &reg; hello">Hello</p>
```

**BONUS**: Here is a list of most [**HTML entities categorized and formatted**](http://www.danshort.com/HTMLentities/) nicely.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use markup in a `title` attribute.

Consider analysing whether you need a superscript R (which is *not* the registered trademark sign), whether you need a trademark indicator in the first place, and if you do, why you would put it into an attribute that may or may not be seen by the user, and usually isn’t.